# Can't retrieve value of a field of type @Collection using DoctrineMongoDBBundle

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-mongodb

I have the following definition of a MongoDB Document (I stripped down parts of the class for brevity):

```
// src/Acme/UserBundle/Document/User.php
namespace Acme\UserBundle\Document

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\EquatableInterface;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\Bundle\MongoDBBundle\Validator\Constraints\Unique as MongoDBUnique;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Document()
 * @MongoDBUnique(fields="email", message="This email is already registered")
 */
class User implements UserInterface, EquatableInterface
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\String
     * @Assert\Email(checkMX=true)
     */
    protected $email;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Collection
     */
    protected $languages = array();
}
```

Next I generate the setters and getters with:

```
php app/console doctrine:mongodb:generate:documents UserBundle
```

I use the User class as usual, working everything fine, I can store instances of user that get correctly stored in mongodb.

Querying with the mongodb's console, I can see how the object is stored and that `languages` stores an array:

```
> db.User.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51c2da8d8b4d24315e9ec3d2"), "email" : "test@test.com", "languages" : [  "en",  "fr" ] }
```

But when I try to retrieve the data:

```
$dm = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager();
$user = $dm->getRepository('UserBundle:User')->findOneByEmail('test@test.com');
```

`$user->getEmail()` returns the E-mail correctly but `$user->getLanguages()` always return an empty array.

EDIT:

I managed to run a query using a CLI Command for `app/console`:

```
$dm = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager();
$user = $dm
    ->getRepository('UserBundle:User')
    ->findOneByEmail('test@test.com');

    print_r($user->getLanguages());
```

And the output of the `print_r` command was correct:

```
Array
(
    [0] => en
    [1] => fr
    [2] => pt
    [3] => es
)
```

EDIT2:

And after that I tried the application again and it worked normally. I don't know why.

Comment: Interesting. Can you try to use `@MongoDB\Hash` instead (which store an associative array) ? - just for curiosity.

Comment: I already tried and the arrays gets stored in associative form like `{0: 'en', 1: 'fr'}` etc

Comment: yes, but do you succeed to retrieve it using `getLanguages()` ?

Comment: Sorry, no, the result was the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had this problem and take a quick look at doctrine mongodb implementation.

Doctrine creates some hydrators classes at runtime (thanks to the class `Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Hydrator\HydratorFactory`) and store the result in the cache. The cache is built on the first request then the cache is used. This is why you had this strange behaviour and resolution.

A simple reset of the cache solves this problem:

```
php app/console cache:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the question after trying to debug using a custom Symfony's `app/console` function to retrieve data, things started working.

I'm not sure why, so... :(

Comment: I don't think this answer should be marked as accepted since there is no solution ;) I have the same problem and can't solve it.